# getElementById to get the ID of the element

Tags: javascript, jsp

Im currently using JSP and need to get the a cell in a table.

the following is of course in a for loop in javascript:

```
var cell=document.getElementById('cell_' + newRow + ',' + i);
```

now on variable cell I need to get the ID. Any ideas how to do that?

if i do alert(cell); then it returns this value: [object HTMLTableCellElement]

Thanks

Comment: 'cell_' + newRow + ',' + i is itself an ID of the element

Comment: What? Why? You have just selected it based on id???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alert(cell.id);
```

should work. You can find whole DOM Element attribute and method reference here:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml

Answer (score 0):

try debuging it and use [Watch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoBWKHt5R4w) on the newRow parameter.

as far as I know its `var cell=document.getElementById('cell_' + newRow.id + ',' + i);`